# Display DPI in image properties

Tags: interface, image, uv-image-editor

Is there a way to display an image DPI in the properties of the Shader Editor?

[image]
For context, I was trying to find a way to automate this in the Group node (or other option). But can't. So I'll leave this as a manual input. For a smoother pipeline, I want to display all information within the Sidebar.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken only printers will use the information on a screen and in a texture, 1px is 1px, regardless of DPI.

Comment: This for accurate print, fabric design, etc placement on garments. All 3D fashion application (such as Clo3D) use this.

Comment: I think those other softwares use it so the end consumer doesn't have to worry about it. Just my guess: It will rescale the texture based on the DPI so it matches printing behaviour. This is not necessary in Blender, if you want to use it, just read the DPI from the file and multiply the size by: (72 / YourDPI) 72 is the standard for screens, as far as I know.

Comment: The primary purpose of the Node Group is to handle the scaling.
It would be great if I could display the DPI of an image. Instead of the user going back and for between apps and folders. Not all design have the same DPI. We work 150, 300, 600 and on rare occasions 1200dpi.

Comment: But how "big" a texture is is solely defined by the UVs, it has nothing to do with DPI. If you want the DPI displayed, I suggest using python to read the header of the image file.

Comment: That is true. But we are using DPI to have correct real world proportions and repeat the texture. Our workflow (to export an object to Blender) is to setup the UV with a real life scale 1 meter. This also places some object outside the UV box. Within Blender, since the UV is constant to 1 meter. I can scale the texture to re-world scale. This is done with the images DPI.                         Hope I need sense.

Comment: In this case I would read the dpi from the image file directly (header) and multiply the uvs by that factor. Or - change the DPI so it is converted to 72.